# getting error while compiling java program

Tags: java

i'm getting this error while compiling the java program  to find the area of square & rectangle using overload constructor .

```
square.java:18: error: <identifier> expected
public Static void main(String args[])throws IOException;
             ^
1 error
```

this is my code

```
import java.io.*;
class area
{
    int a,l,b;
    area(int a1)
    {
        a=a1;
        System.out.println("area of square is " + a*a);
    }
    area(int l,int b)
    {
        l=l1 ;
        b=b1 ;
        System.out.println("area of rectangle is " + l1*b1);
    }
    class square
    {
        public Static void main(String args[])throws IOException;
        {
            int a2,b2,l2,ch;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println("enter your choice 1.square 2.rectangle 3.exit");
                ch=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                switch(ch)
                {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("enter the side of square ");
                        a2=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                        area ar=new area(a2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("enter sides of rectangle ");
                        l2=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                        b2=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                        area ar2=new area(l2,b2);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.exit(0);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Static` is not a valid keyword, for starters. Java is case sensitive, so it should be `static`.

Comment: And I'll be waiting for your next question about the fact that when you run this it will complain there's no `main` method.

Comment: yes it happended :(

Comment: `main` should be inside a top level class, not an inner class. You should follow the advice in TomStroemer's answer and use two separate classes in two separate files. Then compile both and run the one that has the `main` method.

Comment: okay. from now on i'll do that . is it a good programming practice if i use the terminal for compiling and running rather than using an ide . i'm just learning the basics of java .what would you reccommend ?

Comment: While you're starting it's good practice to learn how stuff works under the hood (i.e. manually compiling from the command line). But you'll soon discover it gets complicated very quickly when you start having a lot of files to handle.

Comment: Also, programming is much more than just coding. You need to use version control, refactor code, handle project files, handle packaging and deploy... An IDE helps you with all this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple errors in your file:

```
area(int l,int b)
{
  l=l1 ;
  b=b1 ;
  System.out.println("area of rectangle is " + l1*b1);
}
```

There is no variable l1 and b1. You want to rename your method parameters.

```
public Static void main(String args[]) throws IOException;
```

Static is not a valid keyword. You want to use static. And you don't want the semicolon at the end of the line.

But also - static is not allowed here. You either need to declare your square class in a separate file or you need to make it static

```
static class square {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
  ...
  }
}
```

Also finally your label "2" in the switch case is duplicated.

```
case 2:
  System.out.println("enter sides of rectangle ");
  l2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  b2 = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  area ar2 = new area(l2, b2);
  break;
case 2:
  System.exit(0);
  break;
```

I found all that just by copying your code into an IDE.

Further I would suggest:

- Class names should start with an uppercase Letter. So use `Area` instead of `area` and `Shape` instead of `shape`.
- Move every class to a separate file, so you have a Area.java and Shape.java
- Format your code for readability

Comment: thanks brother. these points are noted. the thing is that i'm new to programming and java. so i am trying to learn the code .that's why not using an ide .although i understood that an ide would helps much in debugging the code .

Comment: Please accept an answer, if your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is write but some where  wrong

i suggest you,
error in line **public Static void main(String args[])

solution is that

`public static void main(String arg[])
    {
    }`

static keyword in small .